# Creating a complex ID using a trigger

Tags: oracle, function, triggers

In many of our applications we use an identity column to generate a unique number, such as a customer_id.

Our internal auditors feel this is a possible breach of security and going forward we want  to use something a bit more complex.

I found a function below base34 that I want to pass a concatenation of SYS_Guid, part of a TIMESTAMP and a sequence number to create a more complex ID.

Below is my test CASE. Is there a way I can use the base34 function in a before INSERT trigger with the above concatenation without changing the base34 function to achieve this task.

For example, let's say I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
 customer_id VARCHAR2 (20),
 first_name VARCHAR2 (20),
 last_name VARCHAR2 (20));
```

And I want the trigger to populate customer_id

Thanks in advance for your time and expertise.

```
create table t ( pk number);

 create sequence seq start with 1000000 minvalue 1000000 maxvalue 9999999 cycle;

 begin
      for i in 1 .. 10 loop
        insert into t values (            to_number(trunc(dbms_random.value(1000,9999))||                      to_char(systimestamp,'FFSS')||
                       seq.nextval));
      end loop;
    end;
/

create or replace function base34(p_num number) return varchar2 is
      l_dig varchar2(34) := 'AB0CD1EF2GH3JK4LM5NP6QR7ST8UV9WXYZ';
      l_num number := p_num;
      l_str varchar2(38);
    begin
     loop
        l_str := substr(l_dig,mod(l_num,34)+1,1) || l_str ;
        l_num := trunc(l_num/34);
       exit when l_num = 0;
     end loop;
    return l_str;
   end;
 /
 
create or replace function dec34(p_str varchar2) return number is
     l_dig varchar2(34) := 'AB0CD1EF2GH3JK4LM5NP6QR7ST8UV9WXYZ';
      l_num number := 0;
    begin
     for i in 1 .. length(p_str) loop
        l_num := l_num * 34 + instr(l_dig,upper(substr(p_str,i,1)))-1;
      end loop;
     return l_num;
   end;
 /

select base34(pk) from t where rownum <= 10;

 select to_char(pk) from t where rownum = 1
    union all
    select base34(pk) from t where rownum = 1
    union all
    select to_char(dec34(base34(pk))) from t where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: So many questions: 1) Why is use of a sequence a possible breach of security? 2) You've made  a more complicated number, but how does this improve security? 3) how does the added computation overhead affect the performance and scalability of your system? 4) have you tried placing the function in a trigger? 5) Where's your code, and what was the result?

Comment: @pmdba the feedback was a sequential number is easier to hack then a concatenation. The concatenation forms a unique alphanumeric string that could be used as a primary key. We haven't done any in depth performance testing as of yet as this project isn't official yet and needs to be run up the ladder. Think of this as a POC. I got stuck putting the function in the trigger. I can go back and update the post with my attempts.

Comment: You probably misunderstood the comment of your internal auditors: the breach of security occurs when the sequentially generated IDs are sent to a UI in clear, not per se when used in the database. When in the UI, it's possible to guess some information like the number of records in the tables and it's possible to attempt to get not displayed records by forging URLs just changing the (e.g.) "id" parameter.
Making complex PK based on strings has drawback on the internal pagination of the  indexes...

Comment: It's far easier to send to the UI an encrypted version of the PK using the SESSION_ID and an internal string as encryption key, the ID seen in the UI will be impossible to use to guess anything, it can't be even copied/pasted to another computer.

Comment: Can your auditors provide any reference which states that a sequential ID is a security risk?

Comment: How do you ensure uniqueness of the generated key (when it is based on random number)?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit from what I understood is that a sequential NUMBER ie 1,2,3... would be easy to guess although I haven't seen any PRIMARY keys defined that simple. I've seen a few applications that start with 5 digits. Secondly, the uniqueness will come from a combination of the GUID, a portion of the SYSTIMESTAMP and a sequence NUMBER. I ran the PLSQL block many times in a LOOP generating upto a million VALUES  each time and didn't see any duplicates. You may ask why not use a 20 digit sequence NUMBER. That's because it may break some applications and would be difficult on users

Comment: Well, if you would use a sequential number for example as an account number, then yes it would be easy to guess an account number which is not yours. However, a so called (surrogate key)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key] is just a plain number and does not mean anything related to the record. Such keys are just used internally and never exposed to the application or end-user.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
 customer_id VARCHAR2 (20),
 first_name VARCHAR2 (20),
 last_name VARCHAR2 (20));


create sequence seq start with 1000000 minvalue 1000000 maxvalue 9999999 cycle;

create or replace function base34(p_num number) return varchar2 is
      l_dig varchar2(34) := 'AB0CD1EF2GH3JK4LM5NP6QR7ST8UV9WXYZ';
      l_num number := p_num;
      l_str varchar2(38);
    begin
     loop
        l_str := substr(l_dig,mod(l_num,34)+1,1) || l_str ;
        l_num := trunc(l_num/34);
       exit when l_num = 0;
     end loop;
    return l_str;
   end;
 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_trg
BEFORE    INSERT 
ON    customers 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.customer_id := base34(to_number(trunc(dbms_random.value(1000,9999))||                      to_char(systimestamp,'FFSS')||
                       seq.nextval));
END;

begin
      for i in 1 .. 100 loop
         INSERT into customers (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('John', 'Doe');
              end loop;
    end;
/
```